# Firebase Cloud function for Push notification

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am able to send the push notification without `delivery_receipt_requested`. On adding the `delivery_receipt_requested` field, I am getting error.
I want to update a field in the database whenever the notification is delivered to the device from Firebase cloud function.

> Error sending message: { Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown
>   name "delivery_receipt_requested" at 'message': Cannot find field.
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
>       at new FirebaseMessagingError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:241:16)
>       at Function.FirebaseMessagingError.fromServerError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:271:16)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request.js:149:50
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)   errorInfo:     { code:
>   'messaging/invalid-argument',
>        message: 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "delivery_receipt_requested" at \'message\': Cannot find field.' },
>   codePrefix: 'messaging' }

my payload structure

```
  var payload = {
                delivery_receipt_requested:true,
                  notification: {
                    title: user,
                    body: snapshot2.val()
                  },
                  android: {
                    notification: {
                    sound: "default"
                    }
                  },
                  token: userToken
                };

 admin.messaging().send(payload)
                .then((response) => {
                    // Response is a message ID string.
                    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
                    return 1;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
                    return 0;
                });
            return snapshot2.val()
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("Error" + userToken2)
            });
```

Comment: I don't see `delivery_receipt_requested` defined in the [documentation for Message structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages).  Where did you find it?

Comment: @BobSnyder my fault. there is not such field. I looked at wrong place. It is used from the app server, So that FCM can confirm delivery. How can I confirm the the delivery of the notification from Firebase Cloud function?

Comment: When the `Promise` returned by `send()` resolves successfully (`send().then(...)`), the server has received and accepted your message.

Comment: How can we verify when device received the message?

Comment: The HTTP API doesn't support that.